# Update AzureAd application registration using terraform's azapi provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I am trying to update application registration after it has been created. My goal is to update `Application ID URI` with its own application id like so, `api://[ApplicationId]`.

Here is the terraform code I have been trying:

```
resource "azapi_update_resource" "update_app_reg" {
  type = "Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01"
  name = "app-reg"
  parent_id = "${azuread_service_principal.app_reg_service_principal.object_id}"

  # Update Application ID URI
  body = jsonencode({
    "properties" = {
      "identifierUris" = [
        "api://${azuread_application.app_reg.application_id}"
      ]
    }
  })

  depends_on = [azuread_application.app_reg]
}
```

However, I get following error:

```
╷
│ Error: invalid resource ID: resource id '00000..00000' must start with '/'
│
│   with module.application_registrations.azapi_update_resource.update_app_reg,
│   on ..\modules\application_registrations\webapi.tf line 94, in resource "azapi_update_resource" "update_app_reg":      
│   94:   parent_id = azuread_service_principal.app_reg_service_principal.object_id
```

So it says `parent_id` is not valid and has to start with `/` however I could not find how to configure `parent_id` and overall `update_app_reg` to update that. I don't want to run azure cli comman in terraform and would like to accomplish this purely using terraform.

Is it somehow possible to update application id uri of an application registration purely using terraform? Note that, the application is already created in previous steps and the operation i require is to update the created application's `Application ID URI` with its own application id.

Comment: The type of Microsoft.Web/sites doesn't look right if you're trying to update an application registration. Also I'd expect you to be using the azuread provider.

Comment: I already use azuread provider in previous steps. The question is about updating the azuread that is already created

Answer (score -1):

> Is it somehow possible to update application id uri of an application registration purely using terraform?

Yes, you can update `Application ID URI` using Terraform for an existing `Azure AD` application. I have followed the below steps update the `Application ID URI`.

1. Create a Azure AD application

```
    provider  "azurerm" {
    features {}
    }
     resource "azuread_application" "app_reg" {
      display_name = "app_reg"
     }
```

2. After creating the application, add the `Application ID URI` value in the same code to update the application

```
    provider  "azurerm" {
    features {}
    }
    data  "azuread_application"  "app-reg" {
    display_name  =  "app_reg"
    }
    resource  "azuread_application"  "app_reg" {
    display_name  =  "app_reg"
    identifier_uris  =  ["api://${data.azuread_application.app-reg.application_id}"]
    }
```

**Terraform apply**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer @VenkatV . However I need a solution that would work in the same directory and the same run. This does not work for me :(

Comment: This gives following error for me: ApplicationsClient.BaseClient.Post(): unexpected status 400 with OData error: InvalidIdentifierUri: The application identifier uri 'api://000...000' is invalid. I made sure that the app ids, display names and all other properties are the same

Comment: Have you tried my code for updating the Azure AD application ID URI?

Comment: Of course I did. I am getting the error i described in my second comment. Also your solution does not work when I have to fix everything in the same run and in the same directory

Comment: Also, your solution creates a new app registration and deletes the old one. It does not update anything.

Comment: Once you create a Azure AD Application without api and next add identifier_uris  =  ["api://${data.azuread_application.app-reg.application_id}"] in same code.it will modify the existing application without destroying.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I am creating an app in the same run. So using `data` is unfortunately not possible (as it has not been created yet). I want to create, then update with its own app id. And your solution creates duplicate application registration.

Comment: Do you want create application with Application ID URI in the same run?

Comment: I would like to create an app and then assign application id uri with its own application id. But you cannot know the application id uri before the resource is created. So i have to create the app first in one step, then update it. but all must be in the same run

Comment: As you can see my output, I also create a application and updated with Application ID URI in the same run. If still destroying existing application while updating Api you can use lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }

Comment: It creates a duplicated one with the same name

Comment: can you please share your terraform plan snip and code what you are trying?